# Angular Migration 2.1 => 4.1.3, weird breaks, functionality changes.

Tags: angular, webpack, migration

I am in the midst of migrating our project to 4.1.3. After getting rid of all compiler errors, I am left with extremely modified behavior.

To illustrate this, I have pushed our angular project to qa:

QA~ https://backend-dot-qa-stareable.appspot.com/

Live~ https://www.stareable.com/

The Modified Behavior I am talking about happens at 2 places I can see.

First: On the live site when you click on a category on the top of the page, you get redirected without a reload to the category you chose.

On QA, The top 'featured' component does not disappear.

Next: If you click on any series, reviews appear below the show title and description.(on Live)

On QA the content is not being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is because of an error which occurs during navigation. Because the error is not caught, the page actually goes to that url, and reloads. The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTitle' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTitle' of undefined
>       at SeoService.setTitle (app.a7fcc9365e47506ad9aa.js:1)
>       at CategoriesComponent.ngOnInit (app.a7fcc9365e47506ad9aa.js:1)
>       ...
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CategoriesComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:20)

You can see this if you open the console, and check the 'preserve log' checkbox. You need to preserve the log, because if there is an error, the navigation will continue and clear your log.

Without any code, it's hard to see where you went wrong. But at least you know now where to look. It looks like the `SeoService` is not injected properly into the `CategoriesComponent`.

The second problem is caused by what seems to be the same issue:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTitle' of undefined
>       at SeoService.setTitle (app.a7fcc9365e47506ad9aa.js:1)
>       at SafeSubscriber.seriesService.getSeries.subscribe.t.errorMessage [as _next] (app.a7fcc9365e47506ad9aa.js:1)

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't even think to check the console with no compiler errors. I will check out these functions and give you the correct answer once I'm done